# Adding a Java Web Service Client in Netbeans that supports streaming with a WCF Streaming Service?

Tags: c#, java, wcf, streaming, basichttpbinding

I have a C# WCF basicHttpBinding Streaming WebService.

The signature of the method that I want to access is:

```
[OperationContract]
    void SendStream(Stream stream);
```

However, when I try to add it as a standard Java Web Service Client into my Netbeans project. The auto-generated proxy method signature gets changed to:

```
void SendStream(byte[] stream)
```

(Basically streaming is removed).

Is there a simple way to achieve streaming on the java side?  I would rather avoid implementing chunking if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF streaming over HTTP is not interoperable. You can't use it outside of .NET world.

Edit: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525097/what-should-i-know-when-developing-interoperable-wcf-web-service) I'm trying to collect not interoperable features of WCF.

Comment: In that case, is chunking the best alternative ? (i.e. sending the file in smaller chunks using multiple service calls) 

In my case I'm expecting sending up to 100megs at a time.

Comment: Yes. You need some chunking mechanism. You can also try to use MTOM for your chunks.

Comment: To simplify to code, should I bother considering simply sending everything out once (without chunking)?