# WCF duplex connection on iPhone?

Tags: c#, iphone, ajax, wcf, web-services

Is there way that a WCF duplex connection can be consumed in iPhone?

Best regards,

Comment: Here is a thread about WCF feature which are not interoperable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525097/what-should-i-know-when-developing-interoperable-wcf-web-service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because `wsDualHttpBinding` is [not an interoperable binding](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/arungupta/archive/2007/08/wshttpdualbindi.html). Only .NET clients can consume it.